# split array into arrays where values of fist array matched

Tags: php

I have two arrays and i want to split 2nd array into arrays where values of fist array matched.

```
$arr1 = array(4, 6, 9, 14);
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
    $split_by = array_search($val, $arr2);
    if ($split_by) {
        $first = array_slice($arr2, 0, $split_by);
        $second = array_slice($arr2, $split_by + 1);

        echo var_dump($first);
    }

}
```

i want arrays like

```
$newarr1 = Array ( [0] => 4 [1] => 6 [2] => 9 [3] => 14 ) 
$newarr2 = Array ( [0] => 5 ) 
$newarr3 = Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 ) 
$newarr4 = Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 14 )
$newarr5 = Array ( [0] => 15)
```

Comment: Could anybody please explain relations between all arrays? I don't get it.

Comment: Shouldn't your first array not be [1,2,3]? And does newarr4 really contains the 14?

Comment: i don't really understand how you want the arrays to be split. $newarr1 could be achieved by foreaching and in_array, but the others seem pretty random to me

Comment: I think the first is just a kind of "rule". First result array is "all numbers between 4 and 6". Second is "all numbers between 6 and 9".

Comment: @Voitcus Brewal I think he wants the second array be splitted into parts defined by the first array.

Comment: ...WAIT. is $arr1 the collection of indices? (hacking something together for you)

Comment: anyway, the example output arrays seem VERY random, don't think he provided a very good example ;-)

Comment: @YellowBird actually, the first result array is 4,6,9,14, and I don't have any clue how these are to be produced (else than copying $arr1).

Comment: @nonchip I think this is just a reminder of the "base" array.

Comment: @anilsingh Could you please return to your question and mark an answer as correct or answer questions we have about it?

Comment: @YellowBird then he forgot the 1,2,3 part.

Comment: @nonchip Or it's just that he starts from the first element or this array, and not from 0.

Comment: yeah, but then it would conflict with his question (split at ... usually means "get before and after ..."). anyway, good point.

Answer (score 1):

I believe something like this is the code you are looking for

```
$arr1 = array(4, 6, 9, 14);
$arr2 = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);
$lastSplitBy = -1;
foreach($arr1 as $val)
{
    $split_by = array_search($val, $arr2);
    if ($split_by) {
        $first = array_slice($arr2, $lastSplitBy+1, $split_by-$lastSplitBy-1);
        echo var_dump($first);
        echo "<br>";
        $lastSplitBy = $split_by;
    }
}
if ($lastSplitBy > -1) {
    $first = array_slice($arr2, $lastSplitBy+1, count($arr2)-$lastSplitBy-1);
    echo var_dump($first);
    echo "<br>";
    $lastSplitBy = $split_by;
}
```

which has the output

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(5) } 
array(2) { [0]=> int(7) [1]=> int(8) } 
array(4) { [0]=> int(10) [1]=> int(11) [2]=> int(12) [3]=> int(13) } 
array(1) { [0]=> int(15) }
```

As you can see, first it splits the array from 0 to the first element of arr1 (0-4, not inclusive), then from 4-6, not inclusive, etc. and I set it up to include the beginning/end of the array (i.e. 1-3 and 15), you didn't specify 1-3 in yours but I think you might want that; if not, it'd be easy to remove

Comment: why do you exclude the "delimiters"?

Comment: got it now. assuming the asker's $newarr1 is wrong, your code works fine.

Comment: @nonchip Yeah, because excluding delimiters made it match his best, lol :P

Answer (score 0):

Believeing that your:
`$newarr4 = Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 14 )`
is actually:
`$newarr4 = Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 11 [2] => 12 [3] => 13 )`

Here is the solution:

```
$arr1   = array(4, 6, 9, 14);
$arr2   = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15);

$tree   = array();
$i      = 0;
foreach($arr2 AS $index => $value) {
    if(in_array($value, $arr1) == true) {
        $i++;
    } else {
        $tree[$i][] = $arr2[$index];
    }


}

$tree[0]    = $arr1;
```

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: assumption is wrong, but keeping code below if someone needs it:

---

Assuming `$arr1` is the collection of indices to split `$arr2` at:

```
function split_arr($arr1,$arr2){
  $out=array();
  $part=0;
  for($i=0;$i<count($arr2);$i++){
    if(in_array($i,$arr1)) $part++;
    $out[$part][]=$arr2[$i];
  }
  return $out;
}
```

Comment: I don't think arr1 is a collection of indices; maybe this is part of where he went wrong, but his code searches through the second array's VALUES, instead of merely trimming by indices (notice his use of array_search)

Comment: yeah, but shouln't that produce output like `((1,2,3),(4,5),(6,7,8),(9,10,11,12,13),(14))`?